# apache commons configuration loads property until "," character

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-config

I want to load configuration (apache commons configuration) from a properties file. My program is:

```java
PropertiesConfiguration pc = new PropertiesConfiguration("my.properties");
System.out.println(pc.getString("myValue"));
```

In `my.properties` I have

```
 myValue=value,
```

with comma

When I run program the output is `value`, not `value, with comma`. Looks like value is loaded until `,` character.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this is [no longer the default behavior in commons-configuration 2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/upgradeto2_0.html#Accessing_Configuration_Properties).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check [Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractConfiguration.html#setDelimiterParsingDisabled(boolean)). You have to setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true) to disable parsing list of properties.

Answer (score 16):

That behavior is [clearly documented](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html), i.e., that `PropertiesConfiguration` treats a value with a comma as multiple values allowing things like:

```
fruit=apples,banana,oranges
```

to be interpreted sensibly. The fix (from the doc) is to add a backslash to escape the comma, e.g.,

```
myKey=value\, with an escaped comma
```

Comment: Note that if you are using profiles with different config files you need to escape twice these ',' commas with '\\,' because the strings are parsed twice.

Comment: @bogdan.rusu Double escaped worked for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Actually propConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true) is working, but you must load the config file after this setting, for example:

```java
propConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration();
propConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
propConfig.load(propertiesFile);
```

Settings won't work if your code like is:

```java
propConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration(propertiesFile);
propConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

[PropertiesConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html) interprets ',' as a value separator.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `\` before the `,`, you escape it, and you can read the value

Example:

```
myValue=value\, with comma
```

You read = `value, with comma` without problems