# Not getting whole tag value when include "," in tag value using apache.commons.configuration.tree.ConfigurationNode.getValue()

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, apache-commons-config

I am trying to read xml using Apache commons configuration

this is my sample xml file

```
<tu tuid="chan@">
        <note>Label for iCare OLTP administration.</note>
        <prop type="maxlength">75</prop><prop type="minlength">1</prop>
        <tuv lang="ES-ES">
               <seg>Programa, tarjetas, cupones y reglas</seg>
        </tuv>
</tu>
```

this is my java code:

```
 List<ConfigurationNode> tuvNode = element.getChildren("tuv");
 List<ConfigurationNode> segNode = tuvNode.get(0).getChildren("seg");                  

 System.out.println(segNode.get(0).getValue());
```

out put is:

```
Programa
```

Actually it is working.problem is when it has "," then it doesn't give rest of other values.i need whole value.any one can give idea.
my expected out put is:

```
Programa, tarjetas, cupones y reglas
```

i really  appreciate

thanks

Comment: also, if you accept to use another xml library, it is very easy with java xml.

Comment: This situation i have to use this library.so i need to how to get whole value.it is working other characters.problems is if there "," it is not return rest of other values...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

',' is interpreted  as a value separator.

try this:

```
setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true); //  to disable parsing list of properties.
```

more details here:
[apache commons configuration loads property until "," character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307318/apache-commons-configuration-loads-property-until-character)

Comment: first  link is not working (http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html) please give correct link.thank you very much

Comment: where I must set this vale  setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true); this is sample code snip  config = new XMLConfiguration(filename);
          
          Node node = config.getRoot();
          List<ConfigurationNode> bodyTag = node.getChildren("body");
          List<ConfigurationNode> elementsInBodyTag = bodyTag.get(0).getChildren();....... List<ConfigurationNode> tuvNode = element.getChildren("tuv");
                  List<ConfigurationNode> segNode = tuvNode.get(0).getChildren("seg");                             
                  String segNodeVal = segNode.get(0).getValue();Thank you

Comment: config = new XMLConfiguration(filename); config.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);                                                                                           I did SetDekimiter true. but it is not working..any way thanks very much for your idea and wating for your  reply

Answer (score 0):

@ guillaume girod-vitouchkina Thanks for your Idea

we have set value like that
initialize Configuration object with no arguments

```
config = new XMLConfiguration();
```

Then disable delimiter

```
config.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
```

after that give xml file name

```
config.load(filename);
```

after that rest of code

useful link[doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractConfiguration.html)